# multi checkbox not working when data bind multiple times

Tags: jquery

intially am called below function in document.ready function. then it give results fine.     when am recall the function checkboxes are not visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMJ7A.png) -- intially getting results fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Cbo.png) -- when recall same function getting result like this

```
 function fnBindMultiMetaData() {
                  
        var output = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Admin/GetMetaDataName',
            success: function (response) {
                output = response.filter(function (asset) {
                    return asset.isActive;
                });
                var object = [];
                output.map((e) => object.push({
                    text: e.name, value: e.id
                }));
                if ($(".multiple-select").length != 0) {
    
                    $(".multiple-select").multipleSelect({
                        data: object
    
                    });
                }
                $select.multipleSelect('checkAll');
    
       
    },
            error: function () {
                $('#pageLoading').hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please give the link of that multi select plugin that you are using

Comment: thanks for reply.. i use destroy keyword when bind second time like $select.multipleSelect('destroy');. it works fine.